# Identify Raster (jpg, png, etc.) or svg file format from ByteString

Tags: c#, wpf, svg

In C# (.NET FW 4.5), is there a way to understand if a bytestring holds an .svg file or any raster file? I use this routine:

```
[...]
byte[] img = System.Convert.FromBase64String(res);
ctrlImage = new BitmapImage();
ctrlImage.BeginInit();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);                                        
ctrlImage.StreamSource = ms;
ctrlImage.EndInit();
```

to convert the stream to a `BitmpatImage`, but now I need to verify if `res` contains an svg file and not a raster file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SVG file format is based on XML. Hence you could try to decode a text string from your image buffer and check if it begins with `<?xml` or `<svg`:

```
bool isSvg = false;

try
{
    var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(img);
    isSvg = text.StartsWith("<?xml ") || text.StartsWith("<svg ");
}
catch
{
}
```

Or maybe you just check if the first byte in the buffer is a `<`, because the raster image formats do not start with that character:

```
bool isSvg = img[0] == '<';
```

Comment: Your solution is interesting. But, are you really sure that raster image formats do not start with '<' ?
PS: "<xml?" or "<?xml" ?

Comment: Yes, the ones I know of (and that are supported by WPF) all start with other characters.

Comment: Ok. Anyway, the xml tag that identify an xml document should be "<?xml" . Can you apply this correction to your answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `BitmapDecoder` class and read `CodecInfo` once decoder is successfully created.

sample

```
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open);
    BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
    // decoder.CodecInfo contains the information about the image type
    stream.Close();
```

[image: example]

your case

```
    byte[] img = System.Convert.FromBase64String(res);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);  
    BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
    // decoder.CodecInfo contains the information about the image type
    stream.Close();
```

Comment: I didn't know the BitmapDecoder...CodecInfo is really interesting. But if I try to decode from a non-image source, an exception will be thrown. Maybe the Clemens' approach is better, 'cause I can avoid exceptions that may slow down the application flow.

Comment: that is for obvious that if you try to decode a non image source that will cause an exception. the answer is to identify the type of image.